# I cant download file from s3 using ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ansible

I want download file from s3 using ansible.

```
- name: Download file from S3
    amazon.aws.aws_s3:
        aws_access_key: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"   
        aws_secret_key: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxx"
        bucket: "bucket-name"
        mode: "get"
        object: "file1"
        dest: "/home/centos/file1"
```

I am getting error like this:

```
TASK [Download file from S3] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/home/centos/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1634047142.42-9501-194847033388166/AnsiballZ_aws_s3.py\", line 102, in <module>\n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File \"/home/centos/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1634047142.42-9501-194847033388166/AnsiballZ_aws_s3.py\", line 94, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File \"/home/centos/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1634047142.42-9501-194847033388166/AnsiballZ_aws_s3.py\", line 40, in invoke_module\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible_collections.amazon.aws.plugins.modules.aws_s3', init_globals=None, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 176, in run_module\n    fname, loader, pkg_name)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 82, in _run_module_code\n    mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)\n  File \"/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 72, in _run_code\n    exec code in run_globals\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_amazon.aws.aws_s3_payload_GMJ5WC/ansible_amazon.aws.aws_s3_payload.zip/ansible_collections/amazon/aws/plugins/modules/aws_s3.py\", line 360, in <module>\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_amazon.aws.aws_s3_payload_GMJ5WC/ansible_amazon.aws.aws_s3_payload.zip/ansible_collections/amazon/aws/plugins/module_utils/core.py\", line 74, in <module>\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_amazon.aws.aws_s3_payload_GMJ5WC/ansible_amazon.aws.aws_s3_payload.zip/ansible_collections/amazon/aws/plugins/module_utils/ec2.py\", line 65, in <module>\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py\", line 16, in <module>\n    from boto3.session import Session\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/session.py\", line 17, in <module>\n    import botocore.session\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py\", line 30, in <module>\n    import botocore.client\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py\", line 16, in <module>\n    from botocore.args import ClientArgsCreator\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/args.py\", line 26, in <module>\n    from botocore.signers import RequestSigner\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/signers.py\", line 19, in <module>\n    import botocore.auth\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/auth.py\", line 121\n    pairs.append(f'{quoted_key}={quoted_value}')\n                                              ^\nSyntaxError: invalid syntax\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}

ansible --version
[WARNING]: log file at /etc/ansible/logs/ansible.log is not writeable and we cannot create it, aborting

ansible 2.9.25
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/icmqa/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Nov 16 2020, 22:23:17) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)]
```

Comment: `Syntax Error` indicates you're trying to install a python 3.x module in 2.x.

Comment: which module do you have in mind and how can I resolve this issue

Comment: As shown in the traceback from the execution: `File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/auth.py", line 121` has the illegal syntax for python 2.7: `pairs.append(f'{quoted_key}={quoted_value}')`; I would _guess_ you just copied `botocore` files over from another python install, since pip should refuse to install packages into incompatible python versions